# pointer with delete that does not reference dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++

> It is possible to use a pointer with `delete` that does not reference
> dynamically allocated memory. Justify why or why not with an example.

In my example, I am doing this:

```
int *ptr; delete [] ptr;
```

Comment: Maybe if `ptr` is `NULL`.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `java` and `c`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Can you please more ellaborate?

Comment: Not sure about C++, but with C it's safe to `free` a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie donot have any tags in mind

Comment: heap and stack have diffrent addresses ranges. and if you try to free pointer that previously not alocated by malloc you will get segmintation fault.

Comment: Please show where and how `ptr` is initialized.  Your real code couldn't possibly just declare a pointer and then immediately `delete ptr;`, does it?

Comment: This looks like a poorly conveyed true-false question from a test. In that case, the answer the test-maker likely wants is “False,” and the correct answer is “True.” That is, it is **possible** to use a pointer that does not reference dynamically allocated memory with `delete`, but you might not like the results. Aside from the special case of using a null pointer, the **intent** of `delete` is to use it with addresses previously provided by `new`, and the behavior is specified for that. The behavior is not specified for passing other pointers.

Comment: Change your example to: `int* ptr = nullptr; delete[] ptr;`  And *voila*, you now have a valid use case that answers the question.

Comment: @FiddlingBits - It is also safe to `delete` a null pointer in C++ (it is a no-op).    However this example has undefined behaviour since the only context in which is it possible to do `int *ptr; delete ptr;` is in a function block (otherwise the `delete ptr` is a diagnosable error) - in which case `ptr` is an uninitialised variable of automatic storage duration, not a null pointer, and accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.   The behaviour if `delete ptr` was changed to `free(ptr)` would also be undefined - in both C and C++ - since `ptr` is still uninitialised.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `delete`'ing something that wasn't returned by `new`, and is not `nullptr`, is *undefined*. The pointer that you `delete` was not returned by `new` and is not `nullptr`, so the behavior of your program is *undefined*.

The value of a default-initialized pointer with automatic storage duration is *indeterminate*. Reading an indeterminate value has *undefined behavior*. Your program reads the indeterminate value of the pointer. The behavior of your program is *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is undefined behaviour, since this does not initialize the pointer to `nullptr`.

The only pointers that can be used with `delete` operator are those that are given by `new` operator or null pointers. See

> its value must be either null or pointer to a non-array object created
>   by a new-expression, or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array
>   object created by a new-expression. If expression is anything else,
>   including if it is a pointer obtained by the array form of
>   new-expression, the behavior is undefined.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete